# CONSTRAINT_ERROR with "index check failed"

Tags: ada, gnat

I'm making an arithmetical expression interpreter in Ada.

Example input: "ADD a b;ADD b c;PRN c;SUB c a;PRN c;"

I have a long code, so I dont want to copy all of that, instead I try to explain the short piece of that, where I have got the error.

's' is a State, represented by a record, with the field 'Size' and an array, called Expressions. An expression is represented by a record, with the fields: Op (enum type), LHS and RHS(Characters).
The function notSpaceLinSearch finds the index of the first element in the input string that is not a space.

So my question is, why the error could be raised, and why just in the 5th time of index referring?

Thanks for your answers in advance.

```
while loopIndex <= numOfExpressions loop
         s.Size := s.Size + 1;
         notSpaceLinSearch(charArray, ' ', contains, notSpaceIndex);
         foundChar := charArray(notSpaceIndex);
         case foundChar is
            when 'A' => s.Expressions(s.Size).Op := ADD;
            when 'S' => s.Expressions(s.Size).Op := SUB;
            when 'M' => s.Expressions(s.Size).Op := MUL;
            when 'P' => s.Expressions(s.Size).Op := PRN;
            when 'I' => s.Expressions(s.Size).Op := INI; -- raised CONSTRAINT_ERROR .... index check failed
            when others => null;
         end case;
....
....
...
end loop;
```

Comment: If the index check failed, the index (`s.Size`) wasn’t within the bounds of `s.Expressions`. And, maybe you need to consider that default `null` in the case statement given that you’ve incremented `s.Size` unconditionally.

Comment: You may want to use `Ada.Containers.Vectors` instead of an array since you won't know the required size of the array beforehand; you can append to a `Vector` and it provides a `Length` function, making it a possible replacement for your array/size combo.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the answers, the problem was the wrong inicialization of the Expressions array. (N-1 instead of N).